# Grep command that matches lines with EXACTLY 2 '*'

Tags: regex, grep

I need help figuring out a command that will search a file and display lines that include *exactly* 2 `*`.

- Valid matches examples: `**`, `*red*`, `manche*ste*r`
- Invalid matches examples: `*`, `***`, `mache*s*te*r`

What I have so far is:

```
grep ‘\*.*\*’ filename.txt
```

But this displays lines that have at least two `*` but not exactly two. And I can't see to find a way to do that.

Comment: Maybe `grep '^[^*]*\*[^*]*\*[^*]*$' filename.txt`?

Comment: That works but could you explain why? Thanks!!
^ - matches at the start of the line
[^\*] - not starting with *
*\* - matches preceding char 0+ times

Comment: you can also use `awk -F'*' 'NF==3' filename.txt` for such cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
grep '^[^*]*\*[^*]*\*[^*]*$' filename.txt
```

The regex matches a string that contains exactly two asterisks with any other chars before, after and in-between them.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`
- `\*` - a `*`
- `[^*]*\*[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`, a `*` and again 0+ chars other than `*`
- `$` - end  of string.

Comment: This is a PITA, but very aesthetically pleasing.